# Two Grid Packages Installed: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I inherited a rather old MVC project that had a Grid package installed, `Grid.MVC`.  It is used extensively, and taking it out or replacing it is not an option (client won't pay for it.)

We just built out a new portal section to the site, and in it, we used a new (and better) grid, NonFactors.Grid.Core.MVC5.  Much more features and options.

But here's the problem.  In all the places where the old grid is used, I now get this run-time error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'NonFactors.Mvc.Grid.MvcGridExtensions.Grid(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' and 'GridMvc.Html.GridExtensions.Grid(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'

This should be a simple fix. All I need to do is tell the old grids which one they are.  But i'm not figuring out the syntax.  In the view's, they all have a `@using` which points to the correct (old) version.

```
@using GridMvc.Html
....
@Html.Grid(Model.Leads).Named("userGrid").Selectable(false).Columns(c =>
{
     ....
}
```

A pic might be more helpful:

[image]

I've tried various means of a full path in the view, but the syntax is never right...

```
@GridMvc.Html.GridExtensions.Grid(Model.Leads)....  // Nope
@Html.GridMvc.Html.GridExtensions.Grid(Model.Leads)....  // Nope
```

etc etc etc.

Again, this is probably simple.  I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the `HtmlHelper` instance as first argument to the extension method:

```
@NonFactors.Mvc.Grid.MvcGridExtensions.Grid(Html, Model.Leads)
@GridMvc.Html.GridExtensions.Grid(Html, Model.Leads)
```

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods are callable as standard static methods, but just take the parent type as a first parameter, so you should be able to pass the `HtmlHelper` as so:

```
@GridMvc.Html.GridExtensions.Grid(Html, Model.Leads)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is correct, but Darrin beat you to it.  Still, much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Disable one of the grid templates from the web.config
in the views folder.
-->